# Process for capturing image, storing it locally, showing it in table view, uploading to server and downloading on other devices?

Tags: objective-c, image-capture, image-management

I want to know about process for managing images for an iOS app dealing with large images. I have done all the steps separately and everything works properly if performed individually. The flow is as given below:

1. Capture image on iPhone (Full sized images of 2-5 MB)
2. Store the image locally on iPhone (where should it be stored in NSUserDefaults or temp folder or coredata?)
3. Show image locally
4. Upload the image to server when internet connection is available
5. Download the image from server (I use SDWebImage) to show on all devices

I can do all the steps independently properly but when these are combined they cause problems in app.
The app requires to capture image and show them to table view from local storage until its uploaded on server.

**Do I need to upload it to server and download it again before even showing to local table view? If not how should it be managed within app** The best case should be that it gets saved in local storage and just uploaded & not downloaded again until its available locally.

Comment: Have a look at parse.com - they have an example app that does exactly this.

Comment: Can you share the link to that sample ?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/tutorials its the first one anypic